# get order details by Order Id in magento

Tags: php, magento

i try to get order details by order id in my code. i create php file and copy that on a folder in public_html. this is my code :

> ```
> <?php 
>  error_reporting( E_ALL );
>  require_once "lib/nusoap.php";
>  require_once "../app/Mage.php";
>   try {
>    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load('100000234');
>    $orderData = $order->getData();
>    print_r($orderData);
>   } catch (Exception $e) {
> echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
>   }
>    ?>
> ```

but when i run code it,s show no things to me ! i try to var_dump($order) but it`s show no thing and no error !
can any body help me to get order detail and show it ?
thanks

Comment: Are you sure your php code is getting executed ? Check the page source and check if its blank too or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this instead

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('100000234');
```

**Updated**

Make sure that you're initiating Magento as well. After including Mage.php, you should have

```
Mage::app();
umask(0);
```

Comment: i use this code but it`s show no thing and no error

Comment: Try to do a small change in above code.
Mage::app('admin'); and also check your error_log file whether there is any php error.

Comment: Thank you after adding Mage::app('admin') ; every thing work fine.